# Django how to DRY code from view

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm just starting coding in Django and I have code that repeat itself on a lot of pages.

for example:

```
<select name="seasons" id="season-id">
    {% for season in seasons %}
        {% if season_id|add:0 == season.id %}
            <option value="{{ season.id }}" selected="selected">{{ season.name }}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ season.id }}">{{ season.name }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

In previous language I could use view helpers to make it more DRY.  How can I accomplish this in Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the code into a separate template file and [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) it instead of repeating:

```
{% include "seasons.html" %}
```

FYI, you can also specify that you want to pass only `seasons` variable into the context of included template:

```
{% include "seasons.html" with seasons=seasons only %}
```

Comment: @Yannick template tags are usually useful when you need to have a custom python logic been used in the template Django doesn't support. Here you have a piece of html code that needs to be reused. For me the choice is pretty clear. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is repeating.

1. You can nest templates. Probably not useful here.
2. You can write your own template tags and template filters. [further info](http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be writing this template code at all. You should define a Django form and let that output the field.